# Web Page - text on image - relative location irrespective of display resolution

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

I like to display text on a specific location of the image. I am using pixel now and i experience the text location moves based on the display screen resolution.

Is there any way to make the location relative to the display resolution? what type of image to be used ?

I tried with relative and absolute and the text moves based on display resolution of my laptop and desktop, which has got HD display

example i tried

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

   img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
        #rcorners2 {
            border-radius: 25px;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 350px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .w3-theme-border {
            border-color: #4CAF50 !important;
                border-top-color: #4CAF50;
                border-right-color: #4CAF50;
                border-bottom-color: #4CAF50;
                border-left-color: #4CAF50;
        }

        .test1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 135px;
        left: 220px;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid green;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="rcorners2" class="w3-theme-border">


           <div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                <img src = "Test.gif"      alt = "image" style="width: 430px; height: 350px;">


            <div class="test1"><b> 12 V : testing </b></div>


           </div>

        </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the output

[image]

Comment: Assuming the image dimensions don't change you should be able to place the image in a `position:relative` div and then some absolute text within the same div. However without example code it's hard to tell what *exactly* you're trying to do.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple, but I could sooner guess your age and weight than solve this without some example of the actual problem.

Comment: sorry, i added the example program